# Uncaught exception in GWT after http request

Tags: java, javascript, exception, gwt, httpwebrequest

I have an web application created with GWT which interacts with a server via http requests to php files. I make a request to the following php file: 
http://localhost/bibliotheek/php/addUser.php?username=username.test2&group=test&admin=false&password=&topadmin=false

When I do this in hosted mode (so after compiling) I get the following exception:

> uncaught exception: [Exception...
>   "'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For
>   input string: ""' when calling method:
>   [nsIDOMEventListener::handleEvent]" 
>   nsresult: "0x8057001c
>   (NS_ERROR_XPC_JS_THREW_JS_OBJECT)" 
>   location: "JS frame ::
>   chrome://firebug/content/spy.js ::
>   callPageHandler :: line 744"  data:
>   no]
>
> Line 0

I get this exception only with this request, not with other requests. I make the request with the following code:

```
protected void addUserToTheDatabase(String[] data) {


    String file = "addUser.php?username=" + data[0] + "&group=" + data[1] + "&admin=" + 
                  data[2] + "&password=" + data[3] + "&topadmin=" + data[4];

    request object = new request(); 
    object.getMessageXml(file, "GET", "null", new AsyncCallback<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            new UserInterface.notification(BibPhp.error.INTERNET_CONNECTION);   
            caught.getMessage();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {

            if(Integer.parseInt(result) == 0) {
                new UserInterface.notification("Deze gebruikersnaam is reeds in gebruik.");
            }
            else {
                new UserInterface.notification("Gebruiker toegevoegd.");
            }
            new add(false);
        }
    });
}
```

I have no idea what I do wrong because all the other requests or exact the same, just to an other file. The php file doesn't generate a a response, so that can make any influence.

Any other people that experienced this problem or any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onSuccess method you do an Integer.parseInt(result).  If the value of result is "" you might get the above exception.  I would confirm that the value of result is actually a number and not an empty string.  You can also put a try ... catch around the parseInt call to catch the NumberFormatException and notify the user.